# Nuxt complains about missing Prop type

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a Nuxt component who's props are defined as follows:

```js
type Props = {
    type: 'element'
    element: 'gold' | 'silver' | 'copper' | 'tin'
} | {
    type: 'custom'
}

// In vue file:
<MyComponent type='custom' />
<MyComponent type='element' element='gold' />
```

Now when I call this component with type 'custom', Nuxt gives a warning that element prop is not provided.

```bash
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "element"
```

I know this is a warning but I want to tell Nuxt that it is not required because the type is total. How do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Have you tried adding `element` to the other part of the union? `{ type: "custom"; element?: never; }`